# Replace a word (based on position/length/line) in a file

Tags: java

I would like to write a java code that should allow to replace a word (characterized by a position, length and line) in a file, by spaces.

I wrote a code to locate the word to replace. But how do I replace that word ?
Should I copy and write to another file ?

I know how to replace a word in a "string line", but I can’t replace it in a file..
Here is the current code :

```
File file = new File("myFile");    
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
String line;
        
int position = 4 ;
int length = 10 ;  
int line_number = 1 ; 

String word = "" ;
int n=0 ;
int line_x = 1 ;


while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(line_x==line_number)
    {
        for(int i=0 ;i<line.length();i++)
        {
            while(i==position)
            {
                if (n<length)
                {
                    word = word + line.charAt(i+n)  ;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                    // Replace the word in the file with spaces
                }
                n++;
            }   
       } 
                
    }
    line_x++ ;
}
        
fr.close();
```

Comment: *"Should I copy and write to another file?"* - Yes.

Comment: You'' probably find it a lot easier to use a string list class: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/40-string-list

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using FileWritter?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filewriter-class-in-java/

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into it.
Copy line by line to another file.